# Getting max precision limit overflow for a very simple calculation

Tags: warning-messages, machine-precision

I've never seen this error on such a simple calculation.
Does anybody know how to fix this annoying error?

[image: A very simple calculation causes the max precision limit to overflow]

Comment: Just noticed it's the a-b that's causing this, when I remove it, it doesn't require a high extra precision anymore.

Comment: If `a` is equal to `b`, and try and calculate `N[a-b, anything]`, you'll get that exact same error, no matter how much you increase the `$MaxExtraPrecision`.